# HTML table to emacs table?

Tags: html, emacs, tabular

Judging by other feats of strength I've seen from the Emacs community, there MUST be a solution out there for this, but I can't seem to find it.

What's a way within Emacs to parse an HTML table and turn it into an Emacs table, either `table.el` or an `org-mode` table?  The only way I can see to do it right now is to drag a chunk of a web page into Excel, then export that to CSV or something & import into Emacs.  But I don't want to rely on either a browser or Excel, I just want to do it within Emacs, or at most with a shell tool.

Answer (score 4):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can convert html to orgmode.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be very robust - here's a snippet (extracted from my real-world example) that it punts on:  http://goo.gl/nvO3u .  I guess I could do some pre-processing to remove the `<p>` tags it seems to be choking on.

Comment: Yeah @KenWilliams that is pretty bad. There is a thread at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-07/msg01108.html discussing some alternatives, but I have not tried them.

Comment: `pandoc --from html --to org =(pbpaste) -o -` to convert from the clipboard to org.